# Проблема создания rails cookie при force_ssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookie, ssl

Есть Rails проект. Он работает по https(`config.force_ssl = true`) и находится на поддомене.

Cookie мне необходим на основном домене и всех его поддоменах, ssl есть только на том, где создается cookie.

Так я создаю cookie:

`cookies.permanent[:my_uid] = { value: @user.id, domain: :all, secure: false }`

А вот что пишет мой браузер об этом cookie:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за `force_ssl: true` игнорируется cookie флаг `secure: false`. Как этого избежать?

Comment: Может, это старая кука? Если её предварительно грохнуть, она создастся такой же?

Comment: убил и создал новую, все так же защищена